# Setting up development Environment for android mini PC

Tags: android, eclipse, usb, driver, usb-debugging

I am trying to deploy a demo app to [android mini pc MK 809II](http://dx.com/p/cozyswan-mk809-ii-android-4-1-google-tv-player-w-1gb-ram-8gb-rom-wi-fi-tf-bluetooth-black-185736), but eclipse is not able to detect the device.

I am running Windows 7 32bit and using eclipse juno for application development.
I have tried to follow following links but nothing has helped me out :-

http://www.codeonastick.com/2013/04/mini-pc-mk809-usb-driver-not-recognised.html

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2083522

any info on this would be highly appreciated

thanks

Comment: If using OSX, on your mini pc make sure usb debugging and connect to pc is turned on.  connect to pc is not save between boots.  usb debugging is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it myself and solution goes like this :-

1. Install driver for the rk30sdk using [moborobo](http://www.moborobo.com/)
2. edit android_winusb.inf and add following line :

   %SingleAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_2207&PID_0006

   %CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_2207&PID_0006&MI_01

   %SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_2207&PID_0010

   %CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_2207&PID_0010&MI_01

   in both Google.NTx86 and Google.NTamd64 area.
3. add driver vendor ID  to the "C:\Users\.android\adb_usb.ini" file. I did it and it WORKED!!! Here is it looks:

   ## ANDROID 3RD PARTY USB VENDOR ID LIST -- DO NOT EDIT.

   ## USE 'android update adb' TO GENERATE.

   ## 1 USB VENDOR ID PER LINE.

   0x2207 MiniPC driver